# cant get files using multer in node js (req.file is undefined)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, multer

i use multer package with node and react and i send a file to node js backend, but always its undefined..
This is React

```
<div className="file-field input-field">
 <div className="btn">
  <span>File</span>
  <input
   type="file"
   name="image"
   id="image"
   onChange={changedImageUpload}
  />
 </div>
 <div className="file-path-wrapper">
  <input className="file-path validate" />
 </div>
</div>
```

and that is onChange file handling method in there i just get first `console.log` but second and third is not printed

```
const changedImageUpload = (e) => {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("image", file);
  console.log(formData, file);
  try {
    const config = {
      Headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    };
    axios
      .post("/uploads", formData, config)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
     .catch((err) => {
       console.log(err);
     });
 } catch (err) {
   console.log(err);
 }
};
```

and its Node codes and multer configure

```
import express from "express";
import multer from "multer";
const route = express.Router();

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(
      null,
      new Date().toISOString().replace(/[\/\\:]/g, "_") + file.originalname
    );
  },
});

const multerFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (
    file.mimetype === "image/png" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/jpg" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/jpeg"
  ) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: multerFilter });

route.post("/uploads", upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {
  try {
    // res.send(`/${req.file.path}`);
    console.log(req.file);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

and import in `app.js`

```
import uploadRoutes from "./Routes/uploadRoutes.js";
app.use(uploadRoutes);

const __dirname = path.resolve();
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/images")));
```

so at printing formData i always get empty object, and if i print `req.file` i get an undefined in node js

Comment: Can you share how you are handling input onChange Event ? does using postman to send requests work ?

Comment: Oh sorry, i forgot to share this.. now i'm adding that

Comment: Have you tested your NodeJS server with Postman? It  allows you to  know the source of the error is the frontend or backend part

Comment: Yeah bro i always get undefined

Answer (score 0):

Your filter function is wrong. You are comparing the `mimeType` to things like `jpg` which isn't a real [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types), so your files are always filtered out.

You need to compare to `image/png` and `image/jpeg` instead.

Comment: yeah u right bro, this was a error, but i fixed it and again its not work again